# Local Password to open host drive

Tags: networking, permissions, vmware, shared-folders, sharing

Setup is:

NAS with multiple shared folders

Shared folders mapped in Windows

Ubuntu VM (VMware), with some of the mapped shares available to the VM

All of these mapped drives are perfectly accessible from Windows, with no issues.  Except for the below issue, all of the shares are usable without having to enter any details.

The issue I'm having is that for one particular share, when accessing it Ubuntu pops up the authentication required message for local authentication (ie the Ubuntu password).  I could just about understand what was wrong if it was asking for a network password, but I can't work out why it is asking for a local password.  I've seen other advice on here and elsewhere about disabling "PasswordAuthentication" in /etc/ssh/ssh_config but I'm loath to do this unless absolutely necessary, in case it stops the ones that already work from working! I'll give it a go if none of the answers on here solve it

All permissions on both the Windows side and NAS side are identical between the ones that work and the one that doesn't, as far as I can tell.

edit: I've just noticed the permission popup says "Authentication required to run gvfsd-admin deamon".  After searching this, I don't appear to have the same issue everyone else is complaining about - they get the popup and can't get rid of it, adding the password works fine for me, but it pops up every time I try to access the share.

edit2: Hmm the permission in ubuntu itself is different but seemingly uneditable:[Permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5FaF.png)

If I try to edit to match the other shares, it immediately goes back to what it was originally (in about half a second or so, it flips back without even closing & reopening the window

Edit3: Ok so I think I've narrowed this down to the previous edit - the permission in ubuntu is: [Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmM4L.png) whereas the ones that are working are: [Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJZ0d.png)

Comment: "for one particular share" details would be welcome, to create a reproduceable example.

Comment: @Luuk I'm not really sure what details I could give you? Though I think I may have added an edit since you replied (wasn't expecting such a quick reply!).

Comment: You are talking bout `Ubuntu`, `Windows` and a `NAS`.  Can you limit your question to just 1 problem, like connecting from Ubuntu to a Windows-Share (or as NAS-Share), and explain which steps you take, and include the actual error message.   When you crated of changed some setting to make this work (like in `sshd_config`) explain what you changed.  Help us to reproduce your problem

Comment: @Luuk Thanks - I think I've narrowed it down to the last edit. I think if I can edit those permissions to match, it'll work, so any idea what could be preventing me from changing those permissions?

Comment: I have no clue what I am looking at when comparing your "Not Working" and "Working" screenshots.

Comment: I think I figured it out - for some reason despite following the exact same process, sometimes the share is being added to (as file browser shows it): "Computer/mnt/hgfs" and sometimes "Administrator root/mnt/hgfs" - those in the admin root need the password, and those not, don't